# What word do I use for "clock times"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Consider the following sentence:

Please indicate between what clock times the session will take place: from _____ (clock time) to _____ (clock time).

That is, the respondent is supposed to fill in, for instance, "3 p.m" and "4:30 p.m." in the slots. I realise it's not called "clock time" in English, but what do I use instead?? Will just "time" work? Or should I use "hours"? And should I use different words in the first instance compared to the latter two (for instance "hours" in the first instance, and "time" in the two latter ones)?

**Added clarification:**

Ok, I realise that in my attempt to create a context for my question, I was misleading. Below is what the actual, authentic text looks like:

> Please fill in sessions:

| Date | From (”clock time”) | To (”clock time”) | Number of hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

Comment: Yes, just 'time' will work.

Comment: What @KateBunting  said. *Please indicate what **time** the session will take place:* Ignore the fact that you're asking for *two* times (start and end), UNLESS the form allows for multiple *different* "start-end time" value pairs to be entered (there's more than one session per day, and/or the times differ depending on day of the week, etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, there are multiple choices etc – a bit hard to explain; what it all comes down to is that I need to say it exactly the way it is in my OP...

Comment: @FumbleFingers see added clarification in my OP

Comment: You don't say anything lile 'clock time'. Those are just cues for you to fill in the blanks. So it should be *From 3 pm to 4:30 pm*. The reader knows they are clock times, but the author has only blanks.

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly!! And it's the word to use in the cues I need! That is, I'm not the one who's supposed to fill it out – I'm the one who's supposed to provide the cues. See also my addition to the OP

Comment: The context still isn't clear to me. Is the respondent able to fill in ***multiple lines*** (with different dates)? If so, use ***times***. If he can only fill in ***one*** line (containing two times; start and end), use ***time***.

Comment: Since the respondent is expected to fill in ***date*** as well as [one or more] ***start+end times***, the text prompt should read *Please indicate what **date and time*** (or ***dates and times***) *the session[s] will take place*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "time" will do.  "Indicate what time the session will take place: from ______  to ______."

Or, even shorter "Indicate when the session will take place."

You don't need anything at all in the brackets.  If you ask "When" the obvious answer is to give a time.

If you are worried that people won't understand, break it down

> Use 24 hour clock for your answers:
>
> Indicate the start time of the session. _______
>
> Indicate the end time of the session. _________

And perhaps give an example.

Or in table form

> Please fill in sessions:

| Session | Date | Start time | End time | Length (hours) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example | 16 June | 15:00 | 16:45 | 1hr 45min |

Comment: Thank you! Thing is, I need to do it the way it is in my OP... But perhaps there just isn't a word in English that would fit??

Comment: @Helen  What do you mean "need to do it".  Please explain why you need to write that way.

Comment: I've tried to clarify in my OP now :) I need to keep the format there, so I can't rephrase and do it in an entirely different way, if you see what I mean. I totally realise it's me who's not being very clear...

Comment: Thank you, JamesK, for editing my OP!! I didn't know how to create a table... And thank you for the addition to your answer – makes perfect sense! And "Length (hours)" is obviously so much better than "Number of hours"!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: would you say the 24 hour clock is more common than the 12 hour clock in the UK? Not that it matters in this particular context, I'm just generally curious :)

Comment: Not in conversational use, but in a "fill in the form in an unambiguous way" then 24 hour clock should be encouraged. People will forget to write am/pm and you are left with an ambiguous time.